# Enterprise Security : Where to Start?

Tags: authentication, attacks, attack-prevention, oauth, saml

I am trying to start self studying of Enterprise Security Context, but always feeling kind of lost among all the specs and standards etc. Unlike software development, this really is a challenge as far as I felt so far. SAML, SSO, OAuth, XACML... there are plenty of stuff to learn about; but frankly I am not sure from where to begin, so that I would understand the possible security threats, and then learn these stuff as answers for them.

I would truly appreciate, if someone could **suggest any blog, book or any other learning resource in order to learn the theories in Enterprise Security Context**, so that I could grab the basics in a perfect manner. I assume that this is something that most of the people keep looking for.

Thank you.

P.S: I see some comments mentioning that this is irrelevant to this forum, since it has been understood as some kind of a product recommendation. Please note that I have only asked for the learning resources/online material kind of stuff, but not specifically the exams or qualifications. This exactly is not a question regarding a bug fix or something like that, but surely is a much relevant question to this context, even if it represents a higher level. Thanks!

Comment: CISSP, CISM, CISA,...

Comment: CISSP text book appears to be something very much worth to buy! I just went through the Table of Contents of the book, and it has a well defined flow! Thank a lot for the hint, Lucas!!!

Comment: You could do a SANS Security Essentials training course. Good way to cover the basics, although they're quite expensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be that you need to narrow the scope a little in order to get started.

Which aspect of security are you interested in. From the list of standards, you seem more interested in application security & especially in authentication and authorisation?

That would be a much easier set of targets to learn at least to begin with.

Also, you may need to be aware of regional and sector differences in security requirements. Banking, health, US vs EU and so on. Each have important differences.

Having decided on a more focused approach, perhaps you could update the question to get some more specific advice?

Comment: Frankly, I do not wish to narrow the scopes of answers, even if I am looking for a narrowed scope (a particular sub domain) to start learning. What you had mentioned further in your response about the other possible important areas are very important for me. That's exactly what I would look for. I just needed to identify a starting point, and then the other important areas to grow my knowledge across gradually.